# Qt Postgresql driver build failed

Tags: qt, postgresql, qt4

I downloaded zip archive of the binaries from Postgresql website, unpacked it.
Then found .pro file in "...\src\plugins\sqldrivers\psql".
When I tried to built postgresql driver (`qmake` and then `nmake` ofc) I get this error messages:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file ''C:/CL/pgsql/lib.obj''
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\V
C\BIN\link.EXE": return code "0x450"
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\V
C\BIN\nmake.exe": return code "0x2"
```

What is `lib.obj` here? There definently no such files in postgres zip archive (I followed instruction and there said that files in posgresql `/lib` and `/include` enough ) where could it be? 
Or, maybe, I missed something?

Here's my `psql.pro` file

```
TARGET = qsqlpsql

SOURCES = main.cpp
INCLUDEPATH += "C:/CL/pgsql/include"
LIBS+="C:/CL/pgsql/lib"
include(../../../sql/drivers/psql/qsql_psql.pri)

include(../qsqldriverbase.pri)
```

Comment: @CraigRinger oh, thanks, thats helped me! You colud post it like an answer, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want `C:/CL/pgsql/lib/libpq.lib` instead, referring to the specific file of interest.

I haven't used QMake in ages, but that's how it looks from the error.

(See RobbieE's answer for the docs link and explanation).

Answer (score 1):

`LIBS` refers to both directories and single files depending on the switches

See the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#libs) for a description on how to use it.